# Access storage directory through JS Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Is there is a way to access the `storage` directory, which is already linked to the `public` directory in JS?

I'm trying to make an upload image form.
Validation script:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
    $marker->photos = $request->photos->store('uploads');
}
```

It saves image in `/storage/app/uploads/`

I can't use this image, because website is in `public` folder, and can't have access to any other folders, so I did `php artisan storage:link` to create a sublink to storage folder.

Now, how can I access the image using 1) PHP 2) JS?

Comment: If you want to make all files in `/storage/app/uploads/` public, you can create a symlink in `public` folder to  `/storage/app/uploads/`. Now all files in `storage/app/upload` are accessible publicly from `yourdomain/uploads` path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the public disk to store the file:

```
if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
    $marker->photos = Storage::disk('public')->putFile('uploads', $request->file('photos'));
}
```

This syntax, similar to the one you are using, it's also possible to specify 'public' disk:

```
$marker->photos = $request->file('photos')->store(
    'uploads', 'public'
);
```

Then you'll can access to it by the url.

Laravel:

```
$url = asset('storage/uploads/filename.png');

$url = asset( Storage::url('uploads/filename.png') );
```

JS:

```
let imgSrc = "http://yourdomain/storage/uploads/filename.png";
```

**References:**

File Storage [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads).

File Storage [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

File Storage [File URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls).

Answer (score 2):

From PHP, you would use something like this to access your `storage/` directory:

```php
if(file_exists('storage/app/uploads/photo.jpg')){
    $marker->photo = Storage::disk('local')->get('public/app/uploads/photo.jpg');
    // or to get the directory, which you can append ->response('png') to the end...
    $marker->photo = public_path('storage/app/uploads/photo.jpg');
}
```

To serve it from JS, you would do something similar, but have a Controller output the image when receiving an AJAX Request. Easiet method to achieve this without all this, if possible, would be through a blade template:

```
<img src = "{{asset('/storage/app/uploads/photo.jpg')}}">
```

which generates a link to the uploaded file by Laravel.