# How to display a user avatar using the file storage symbolic link?

Tags: php, laravel, image, symlink, laravel-7

I'm trying to display the user avatar that is uploaded by the user. The image is being saved on the server But whenever i try to display it gives a 404 not found error.

I'm saving the image using this :

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('avatars');
```

I already created a symbolic link using the `php artisan storage:link` command as the [documentation suggests](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem)

My HTML:

```
@if(config('adminlte.usermenu_image'))
        <img src="{{ Auth::user()->adminlte_image() }}"
             class="user-image img-circle elevation-2"
             alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}">
    @endif
```

I'm using the [Laravel-adminLTE package](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE) and using the function below to send the image URL to the view

```
public function adminlte_image()
{
    return Storage::url($this->avatar);
}
```

My folders:

[image]

The Error:

```
 http://localhost:8000/storage/avatars/S8Npk86Zun9FAYBREgxgOh9Ye6xiHVhyAmm3Vhb1.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

filesystems.php:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

I already look several questions here in SO about the symbolic link but i couldnt find the answer.  I'm clearly missing something here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well obviously the `app` folder is missing from your path.

Comment: You should use the 'public' disk when you storing the file.

Comment: Looks like its documented here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem but I am no Laravel expert

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61869276/7498116

Comment: so, i need to specify the disk using ``Storage::disk('public')``? i thought laravel used the public disk as default

Comment: oh, nevermind. Using `$request->file('image')->store('public');` solved the problem. Thank you @porloscerrosΨ for the help. I should have configured the public driver to ``'root' => storage_path('app/public/avatars'),``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was storing the image in the wrong disk. My `filesystems.php` was pointing to the `/public` directory. And i stored the image in `/avatars`.

Changing the path to :

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/avatars'),
```

And the storage method to :

```
$path = $request->file('imagem')->store('public/avatars');
```

Solved the problem